# regular expression in urls. py in django 2.0

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

How can I write these two urls including their regular expression in django 2.0? Huge thanks.

```
url(r'^page/(?P<id>\S+_[0-9]{3,})', views.pageinfo, name="page"),
url(r'^something/(?P<id>\S+)/', views.jsoninfo, name="testinfo2"),
```

Comment: This should work in django 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django 2.0, `url` has simply be renamed `re_path` and moved into `django.urls`:

```
from django.urls import re_path

re_path(r'^page/(?P<id>\S+_[0-9]{3,})', views.pageinfo, name="page"),
re_path(r'^something/(?P<id>\S+)/', views.jsoninfo, name="testinfo2"),
```

Details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 3):

In Django 2+, [you don't need to use regular expressions in your urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax), you can use `path` as follows:

```
path('page/<int:id>/', views.pageinfo, name="page"),
path('something/<int:id>/', views.jsoninfo, name="testinfo2"),
```